# Query parameters not present in $state object

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using ui-router to access url query parameters, so I navigate to:

```
/login?token=test
```

And log `$state`. The `$state.params` is present but is an empty object, yet I have clearly defined the parameters in the url. How can I access these?

console.log($state.current) gives:

```
Object {url: "/login", templateUrl: "js/modules/session/login.html", resolve: Object, name: "login"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer to this, I needed to add the parameter in the state configuration:

```
.state('login', {
      url: '/login?token',
      templateUrl: 'js/modules/session/login.html'
});
```